# How to update MultiIndex after dropping columns in a Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I cannot find how to update a **column** `MultiIndex` with dead values after columns have been dropped. I have [read documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html), but I do not find a method that fit my needs.

**MWE:**

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['41B001', '41B004', '41B011', '41MEU1', '41N043', '41R001', '41R002', '41R012', '41WOL1'], ['CO', 'NO', 'NO2', 'O3', 'PM-10.0', 'PM-2.5', 'SO2']],
           labels=[[1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8], [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]],
           names=['sitekey', 'measurandkey'])
```

Keys `41B001`, `41MEU1`, `41R001` and `CO`, `NO`, `PM-10.0`, `PM-2.5`, `SO2` have been removed but there are still referenced in MultiIndex. I would like a new index without those labels.

Following command does the trick, but it do not find it clean:

```
data3.T.reset_index().set_index(['sitekey', 'measurandkey']).index
```

Returns what I expect:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['41B004', '41B011', '41N043', '41R001', '41R012', '41WOL1'], ['NO2', 'O3']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['sitekey', 'measurandkey'])
```

Is there a better way (efficient, cleaner, pythonic, pandas friendly) to achieve this working only on `MultiIndex` instead of transposing the DataFrame?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2770), [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8893). It is long term bug.